# How to extract object data from Rdata file via command line?

Tags: r

Is there a way to do this? I want to write a bash script that can extract data from an object in an RData file and write it to a text file.

Comment: Can you not use `Rscript` from the command line to read in the RData file and perform whatever data extraction operation you want to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Without being too certain about the specifics of your request (please see about creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), does something like this work:

Assuming your .Rdata is called 'mtcars.Rdata' and contains a `data.frame` called `mtcars` and you want to write it to `mtcars.csv`.

You may have to change the path to where your Rscript.exe file lives.

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin\Rscript" -e "load('mtcars.Rdata', env <- new.env());write.csv(env$mtcars, 'mtcars.csv')"
```